# How to find which program encrypted my files?

Tags: ransomware, code-execution

I've been infected by a ransomware and all files have extension .lin. how can i find the program that encrypted my files ?

Comment: If its ransomware has there been no popup asking for payment? If so then was there no name of the software? Most recent ransomware is well coded enough (as a result of being an off the shelf product these days) that unless you have the key knowing the underlying encryption mechanism won't help.

Comment: Unfortunately, we are not a malware removal and forensics site.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

.lin Extension Virus is quite a bad worm, file-encrypting virus.

It is known to delete users encrypted data after if receiving the ransom money, so the ransom is a no-go anyway.

SpyHunter is a known tool that removes the virus.

[Here](https://www.pcmalwaresecurity.com/ransomware/solved-remove-lin-extension-virus-forever-lin-extension-virus-removal-guide/) is a complete guide for this issue.